# Freeze Variables in TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

Has anyone used the `freeze_variables` field in tfod?
I'm trying to use it in the config file with a regex this way:

`freeze_variables: "\*FeatureExtractor\*"`

so that all the variables of the feature extractor will be frozen, but I can't, for the life of me, figure out whether it is working or not.

Am I doing anything wrong?
How can I tell if variables are frozen or not?
Will tensorboard give me any indication of something like that?

Any guidance will be highly appreciated

Comment: Even I am looking to figure out the same. Any references on where did you find this?

Comment: Specifically for the tfod api, I was not using it the correct way. the freeze_variables in the .config file accepts a list of patterns to be searched in the trainable variables list as produced by tf.trainable_variables. You can enter a list of specific layers, in which case there will be only one match per entry, or you can enter a list of patterns where all matching ops names will be selected. So if you want to freeze all the ops of the feature extractor, you should enter ["FeatureExtractor"].

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> Specifically for the tfod api, I was not using it the correct way. the
> freeze_variables in the .config file accepts a list of patterns to be
> searched in the trainable variables list as produced by
> tf.trainable_variables. You can enter a list of specific layers, in
> which case there will be only one match per entry, or you can enter a
> list of patterns where all matching ops names will be selected. So if
> you want to freeze all the ops of the feature extractor, you should
> enter ["FeatureExtractor"] (paraphrased from tom)

For more information, you can refer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/7511#issuecomment-529785866)